# Processing instructions transform

Tags: xslt

I want to transform processing instructions in a source xml to some tag in an output

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <?PI_start?> SOME TEXT <?PI_end?>
</root>
```

**I want to have the output xml like that**

```
<root>
    <tag> SOME TEXT </tag>
</root>
```

Can I do it? If yes what xsl must I use for transform?

I found only a way to transform PIs to the opening and closing tags. PI can contain some content.

**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <?PI SOME TEXT?>
</root>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI')">
    <tag><xsl:value-of select="."/></tag>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
<tag>SOME TEXT</tag>
```

But this is a bit not my case

Comment: Excellent question, +1. See my answer for a solution that uses the full power of the most fundamental XSLT design patterns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_start')">
  <tag>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select=
       "following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]"/>
  </tag>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "processing-instruction('PI_end')
 |
  text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1]
              [self::processing-instruction('PI_start')]]
 "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <?PI_start?> SOME TEXT <?PI_end?>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <tag> SOME TEXT </tag>
</root>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The *identity rule* is used** to copy all nodes "as-is".
2. **We have additional templates only for nodes that should be changed** in some way.
3. **The template matching the first PI "does almost all the work".** It creates a `tag` element and applies templates to the following-sibling node if it is a PI.
4. **We apply templates in mode "copy" for the text node immediate sibling of the first PI**.
5. **The mode "copy" isn't declared anywhere and this causes the default template for processing text nodes to be selected** -- its action is to just copy the text node. This is a trick that saves us from the need to define a template in the "copy" mode.
6. **We have an empty template that actually deletes the unwanted nodes**: the second PI and what would be a second copy of the first PI's immediate-sibling text node.

**Update**: The OP has indicated that he is also interested in the case where in-between the two PIs there might be different nodes (not only text nodes).

**This is a lot more complex task and here is one solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSurrounded" match="node()"
  use="concat(
        generate-id(preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('PI_start')[1]),
        '+++',
        generate-id(following-sibling::processing-instruction('PI_end')[1])
             )"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_start')">
  <tag>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select=
       "key('kSurrounded',
             concat(generate-id(),
                   '+++',
                   generate-id(following-sibling::processing-instruction('PI_end')[1])
                   )
             )"/>
  </tag>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "processing-instruction('PI_end')
 |
  node()[(preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('PI_start')
         |
          preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('PI_end')
          )
           [last()][self::processing-instruction('PI_start')]
        and
         (following-sibling::processing-instruction('PI_start')
        |
          following-sibling::processing-instruction('PI_end')
          )
           [1][self::processing-instruction('PI_end')]
        ]
 "/>

 <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when the above transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<root>
    <?PI_start?> <strong>Some</strong> TEXT <?PI_end?> XA <?PI_end?>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct output is produced**:

```
<root>
    <tag>
        <strong>Some</strong> TEXT 
    </tag> XA 
</root>
```

Comment: @Dimitre: Isn't the "strip text nodes" rule very general? Wouldn't it be better a groping between tags approach?

Comment: @Alejandro: No, why do you think that this directive should not be used?

Comment: @Dimitre: Maybe `text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::processing-instruction('PI_start')]]` would be better. Don't you think?

Comment: @Alej, yes, I was going to say the same thing. In other words, @Dimitre's code would lose any text that immediately follows `<?PI_end?>`. If the input can have such text. The example didn't, but we don't know that about the real input.

Comment: @Alejandro, @LarsH: C'mon guys, I don't understand at all what you are saying. Which template?

Comment: @LarsH: OK, I see what you're saying: Yes, I fixed this.

Comment: Great answer! In my concrete use case I have xml input what transforms to html. Output html - it is visual presentation of xml data. In input I have some metadata about errors. I want to show these errors in html. For example I have <link href="link.html"/> and this link is incorrect. In html this will look <span class="redunderlined"> <a href="link.html"></span>. But error scope bounded by Process Instructions may have several tags

Comment: @Dimitre: Now is excellent. +1 Also for ussing built-in rules propagation in every mode.

Comment: @Dimitre: @Nawa just wrote *But error scope bounded by Process Instructions may have several tags*. This leads to the grouping between marks approuch...

Comment: @Alejandro: What does @Nawa want to say? I don't understand it.

Comment: @Nawa, @Alejandro, @Lars: I have edited my answer and added the solution for the more complex problem.

Comment: Proposed solution has one drawback - it leads to double processing of tags between processing instructions. Can you suggest how to avoid applying templates for tags between processing instructions after finishing template - <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_start')">?

Comment: @Nawa: There is no "double processing". There is no processing in the template with the empty body. There are nodes that are selected by more than one template -- true. However the second template just does nothing  -- ignores them. This has really intractible additional performance cost. On the other side, not limiting to fine-grain, one node at a time processing, allows the (theoretical) possibility of templates being executed in parallel on multi-core architecture.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Beautiful Explanation Sir, Have added  your answer to my favorite list.

Answer (score 1):

I propose another way to solve my problem. I hope that is correct

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_start')">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<tag>]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI_end')">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</tag>]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

**Input**

```
<root>
    <?PI_start?> <strong>Some</strong> TEXT <?PI_end?> XA <?PI_end?>
</root>
```

**Correct output is produced**

```
<root>
    <tag> <strong>Some</strong> TEXT </tag> XA </tag>
</root>
```

Comment: Always try to avoid DOE -- not only does it break the XSLT architecture, but it isn't a mandatory XSLT feature and is not guaranteed to be supported by any/all XSLT processors.

Comment: Dimitre, what is "DOE"?

Comment: DOE must be: disable-output-escaping="yes"