# How to get the properties from processing-instructing() and store in Global variable in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have more than one processing-instructions in xml, but have to get specific PI(i.e xpp:PageOption) and stored in Global variable.how can i achieve this. Please help me

Please find the below sample input mark-up.

```
                        <?xpp xpp:ps1?>
                        <tag name="html"/>
                        <?xpp xpp:Formater username=&quot;name&quot; ?>
                        <t x="0" y="0" style="html" cgt="true" suppress="true">FirstName LastName</t>
                        <?xpp xpp:PageOptions  showpage=&quot;yes&quot; height=&quot;10&quot; fonttype=&quot;times&quot; linespace=&quot;single&quot; >
                        <tag name="meta">
                            <attr name="http-equiv">Content-Type</attr>
                            <attr name="content">text/html; charset=UTF-8</attr>
                        </tag>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165325/processing-instructions-transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with `<xsl:variable name="pi1" select="//processing-instruction('xpp')[contains(., 'xpp:PageOptions')]"/>` you can select the processing-instruction with name `xpp` which contains the string `xpp:PageOptions` in its data. You need to be aware that the data of a processing-instruction is unstructured, it often looks like a list pseudo attributes but there are no rules on the structure of the data and thus if you expect a certain structure you need to process the data as a string.